# How to speed up listview control?

Tags: android

I use a customize listview control to display image and other informations. The listview control is little slow when I scroll it to display more content.

After I test the control, I find the function `SetControlsValue` to do many works. I must to do some work to improve it.

The **Method 1** is my way, is it correct? is there other the better way?

**Method 1**

```
 private void SetControlsValue(ViewHolder holder,int position){

        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mListCheckedStatus.get(position));

        new BMPOperation().execute(position,holder);

        new LongOperation().execute(position,holder);
    }

    private class BMPOperation extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ViewHolder myHolder;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            int position=(Integer)params[0];
            myHolder=(ViewHolder)params[1];

            Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo();

            return mBitmap;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap mBitmap) {
            try {
                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    myHolder.imageViewthumb.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Utility.LogError(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }



    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
        private ViewHolder myHolder;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            int position=(Integer)params[0];
            myHolder=(ViewHolder)params[1];
            String s=mListVideo.get(position).fileName
                    +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleResolution)+ mListVideo.get(position).GetResolution()
                    +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleSize)+mListVideo.get(position).GetSize()
                    +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleDuration)+mListVideo.get(position).GetDuration();

            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            myHolder.tvInfo.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

**The Function SetControlsValue**

```
private void SetControlsValue(ViewHolder holder,int position){
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mListCheckedStatus.get(position));

        Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo();

        try {
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                holder.imageViewthumb.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Utility.LogError(e.getMessage());
        }

        String s=mListVideo.get(position).fileName
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleResolution)+ mListVideo.get(position).GetResolution()
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleSize)+mListVideo.get(position).GetSize()
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleDuration)+mListVideo.get(position).GetDuration();
        holder.tvInfo.setText(s);
    }
```

**ListVideoAdapter.java**

```
public class ListVideoAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private List<Video> mListVideo;

    private List<Boolean> mListCheckedStatus;

    public ListVideoAdapter (Context context){
        mContext=context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mListVideo= VideoHelper.ListVideo(mContext);

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mListVideo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter_video, null);
            IniControls(holder,convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SetControlsPosition(holder,position);
        SetControlsValue(holder,position);
        SetControlsEvent(holder);

        return convertView;
    }


    private void IniControls(ViewHolder holder,View convertView){
        holder.mCheckBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chSelect);
        holder.imageViewthumb=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewVideo);

        holder.tvInfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);


        holder.imageViewTrim=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTrim);
        holder.imageViewShare=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShare);
        holder.imageViewInfo=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewInfo);
        holder.imageViewDelete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDelete);
    }


    private void SetControlsPosition(ViewHolder holder,int position){
        holder.id=position;
        holder.mCheckBox.setId(position);
        holder.imageViewthumb.setId(position);

        holder.tvInfo.setId(position);

        holder.imageViewTrim.setId(position);
        holder.imageViewShare.setId(position);
        holder.imageViewInfo.setId(position);
        holder.imageViewDelete.setId(position);
    }


    private void SetControlsValue(ViewHolder holder,int position){
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mListCheckedStatus.get(position));

        Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo();

        try {
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                holder.imageViewthumb.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Utility.LogError(e.getMessage());
        }

        String s=mListVideo.get(position).fileName
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleResolution)+ mListVideo.get(position).GetResolution()
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleSize)+mListVideo.get(position).GetSize()
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleDuration)+mListVideo.get(position).GetDuration();
        holder.tvInfo.setText(s);
    }


    private void SetControlsEvent(final ViewHolder holder) {


    }

}



class ViewHolder {
    int id;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
    ImageView imageViewthumb;

    TextView tvInfo;

    ImageView imageViewTrim;
    ImageView imageViewShare;
    ImageView imageViewInfo;
    ImageView imageViewDelete;

}
```

**Added**

I have read the sample code of UniversalImageLoader.

I don't think UniversalImageLoader control fit my requirement.

ImageLoader need to pass URL par

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(IMAGE_URLS[position], imageView, options);
```

but in my app, there are other two codes which spend much time.

1. `Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo();`
2. `String s=mListVideo.get(position).fileName                            +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleResolution)+ mListVideo.get(position).GetResolution()                            +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleSize)+mListVideo.get(position).GetSize()                            +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleDuration)+mListVideo.get(position).GetDuration();`

so I think I need the other better way to improve code.

**BTW**, in my function `Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo()` not only get the thumbnail of a video, but also I need merger a Play icon to the thumbnail, so I don't think I can use `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file:///mnt/sdcard/myvideo.mp4", imageView)`.

Comment: how are you loading the bitmaps? could you please show us the code that set the bitmap to your model?

Comment: Have you considered using caches?

Comment: And more, the following code spend much time.  String s=mListVideo.get(position).fileName
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleResolution)+ mListVideo.get(position).GetResolution()
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleSize)+mListVideo.get(position).GetSize()
                +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleDuration)+mListVideo.get(position).GetDuration();

Comment: I have already suggested that instead of saving the bitmaps, just save the fileNames and get those file names to be used in ImageLoader like `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file:///mnt/sdcard/myvideo.mp4", imageView);`

Comment: Thanks! but in my function Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo()  not only get the thumbnail of a video, but also I need meger a Play icon to the thumbnail, so I don't think I can use ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file:///mnt/sdcard/myvideo.mp4", imageView)

Answer (score 0):

Showing `Bitmaps` on `UiThread` is a lazy operation. So you should you `UniversalImageLoader` to display your bitmaps/thumbnails of videos in `SetControlsValue` function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, Instead of using `holder.imageViewthumb.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);` in your code, integrate `UniversalImageLoader` (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and then try to set image bitmap using `ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();` `imageLoader.displayImage(bitmapUri, holder.imageViewthumb);`

Comment: Thanks! the code "Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo();" spend much time too, can I use UniversalImageLoader to improve speed?

Comment: Yes you can use ImageLoader, instead of saving `BitMapOfVideo`, save `Uri` and then use that `GetUriOfVideo()`in UniversalImageLoader.

Comment: Thanks, and is "private class LongOperation ..." need? because of the following  code need spend much time.  String s=mListVideo.get(position).fileName +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleResolution)+ mListVideo.get(position).GetResolution() +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleSize)+mListVideo.get(posit‌​ion).GetSize() +"\n"+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.TitleDuration)+mListVideo.get(p‌​osition).GetDuration();

Comment: There is not need of this `LongOperation`, you just need `mListVideo.get(position).fileName` which will be used in the `ImageLoader`

Comment: Can ImageLoader operate other control? you know I use  TextView tvInfo control to set text of S;

Comment: Can ImageLoader operate other control? you know I use  TextView tvInfo control to set text of S;

Comment: I know about `ImageView`s but you might create `CustomLoader` which can operate over textviews but not sure

Comment: Thanks! I updated my post, would you please see the "Added" part?

Comment: But in my function Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo() not only get the thumbnail of a video, but also I need merger a Play icon to the thumbnail, so I don't think I can use ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file:///mnt/sdcard/myvideo.mp4", imageView)

Comment: there is no need of merger. You can use separate the play icon and then add on the thumbnail. Imageloader itself creates the thumbnail for you, you dont need to create the thumbnail as well

Answer (score 0):

Here are suggestion to improve the performance:

1. **Use recyclerview instead of Listview -** Recycler view recycles the child items which is out of the screen and thus freeing up the memory
2. **Use picasso image loader -** It loads images on other thread and thus doesn't block your UI thread. Also it caches the image in file/memory (you can configure it) so when user tries to play with scroll your UI doesn't get stuck. This means images which has been already downloaded from network will be reloaded from cache automatically. ( http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Thanks! would you please see the "Added" part in my post? In my function Bitmap mBitmap=mListVideo.get(position).GetBitmapOfVideo() not only get the thumbnail of a video, but also I need merger a Play icon to the thumbnail, so I don't think I can use such as ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file:///mnt/sdcard/myvideo.mp4", imageView)